# Can't use program because file is already in use

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to run my program without Data.txt created already, but every time I do it shows up with the error: "The process cannot access the file 'path' because it is being used by another process."

Here is the area that the code has the error, to be clear it's on the line that says 'StreamWriter Data = new StreamWriter("Data.txt")'

```
dataCheck = @"Data.txt";
dataExists = File.Exists(dataCheck);

if (dataExists)
{
    StreamReader Data = new StreamReader(@"Data.txt");

    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        //takes lines from text file and stores them in an array
        activities[i] = Data.ReadLine();
    }

    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        try { activityTimes[i] = Int32.Parse(Data.ReadLine()); }
        catch {

            StreamWriter DataWrite = new StreamWriter("Data.txt");

            DataWrite.Write(activities[0] + "\r\n");
            DataWrite.Write(activities[1] + "\r\n");
            DataWrite.Write(activities[2] + "\r\n");
            DataWrite.Write(activities[3] + "\r\n");
            DataWrite.Write(activities[4] + "\r\n");

            DataWrite.Write(activityTimes[0] + "\r\n");
            DataWrite.Write(activityTimes[1] + "\r\n");
            DataWrite.Write(activityTimes[2] + "\r\n");
            DataWrite.Write(activityTimes[3] + "\r\n");
            DataWrite.Write(activityTimes[4] + "\r\n");

            DataWrite.Close();
    }

    }
}
else
{ 
    //creates data file with activities and times
    File.Create(dataCheck);
    StreamWriter DataWrite = new StreamWriter("Data.txt");


    DataWrite.Write(activities[0] + "\r\n");
    DataWrite.Write(activities[1] + "\r\n");
    DataWrite.Write(activities[2] + "\r\n");
    DataWrite.Write(activities[3] + "\r\n");
    DataWrite.Write(activities[4] + "\r\n");

    DataWrite.Write(activityTimes[0] + "\r\n");
    DataWrite.Write(activityTimes[1] + "\r\n");
    DataWrite.Write(activityTimes[2] + "\r\n");
    DataWrite.Write(activityTimes[3] + "\r\n");
    DataWrite.Write(activityTimes[4] + "\r\n");

    DataWrite.Close();
            }
```

If anyone could explain the error/provide me with a solution I would greatly appreciate it!

Comment: `Data` and `DataWrite` are pointing at the same file. I suspect you want to `Data.Close()` before trying to write to the file.

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/117902/find-out-which-process-is-locking-a-file-or-folder-in-windows may also be of interest.

Comment: If you are mean using Data.Close() after activities[i] line in the for loop, it still gives me the same error message.

Comment: Is there a way of checking what process is using the file? I really need to solve this issue but I'm stuck.

Comment: You can use StreamReader.BaseStream to check what resource is being used by your object of stream reader. But I think if you use data.close() after first for loop and file is not in read-only mode there should not be any errors.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you're having in the scenario where the file does not exist is that you call `File.Create`, which creates the file and opens a stream on it. This is blocking you from then using the `StreamWriter` on the same file. Remove the `File.Create` since it is not required: `StreamWriter` will create the file.

Some other tips: `StreamReader` and `StreamWriter` are both `IDisposable` so should each be in a `using` block. As a bonus, this avoids you needing to call `Close` which is done by the implicit `Dispose`. You should think of these `using` blocks as being the period of time when the file is open, so since they are accessing the file, they need to not overlap.

Rather than `DataWrite.Write(activities[0] + "\r\n");`, consider doing `DataWrite.WriteLine(activities[0]);`.

You've declared a variable to hold the filename, so use the variable, rather than duplicating the filename in multiple places.

There are two identical large chunks of code which create the file. Refactor this into a method and call the method from both places.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to create a `StreamReader` and then a `StreamWriter` pointing to the same file by specifying the file name (and not closing the first one before opening the second). You can't do that. For example, this code will give the same result:

```
public static void Main()
{
    StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("data.txt");
    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("data.txt"); //: 'The process cannot access the 
                                                    // file 'data.txt' because it is being used 
                                                    // by another process.'

}
```

Instead you can create a `FileStream`, and then create a `StreamWriter` and `StreamReader` from that one `FileStream`. See below:

```
public static void Main()
{
    using (var fs = new FileStream("data.txt", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite))
    {
        using (var sw = new StreamWriter(fs, Encoding.ASCII, 1024, true))
        using (var sr = new StreamReader(fs, Encoding.ASCII, false, 1024, true))
        {
            sw.WriteLine("Hi");
            sw.Flush();           //Make sure everything is fully written to the file.
            fs.Position = 0;      //Go back to the beginning of the file, so we can read it.
            Console.WriteLine(sr.ReadLine()); //Hi
        }

    }
}
```